# Python Matrix Parameter Passing mutated

Tags: python, matrix

Can someone help me out! 
I can't find the reason of the error. If I run it 1 time it works fine however when I call the same method again with the same parameters it keep the last session of the list when I never save it. I tried using a temporary variable but even that got modded after I run it once. :(:(
This algorithm is:

```
def searchin(position, mattwo):
    listpos = -1
    indexone = -1
    # - - - - - -
    for i in mattwo:
        listpos += 1
        for o in i:
            if o == position:
                indexone = i.index(o)
                return listpos, indexone

def repos(reposition, listsone):
    cero, replacement = searchin('0',listsone),searchin(reposition,listsone)
    modded = listsone
    modded[replacement[0]][replacement[1]],modded[cero[0]][cero[1]] = '0', reposition

mat = [['5','4','1'],
       ['0','6','8'],
       ['7','3','2']]

repos('5',mat)
repos('7',mat)
```

The method serachin() returns the position in the matrix 3x3 of the element we are looking for. Is working fine no errors there

The repos() method is the problem. After I run it, the matrix mat gets mutated with the results of last run BUT I never save that.

Comment: What is the error? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I mean no error of crash but is saving the repositioned matrix even if I have a temporary variable somewhere else not being used

Comment: @GiovannieSanchezDiaz the fact that you have `pass` as the last line in your function is a pretty clear sign that you have no idea what you're doing.  that's fine, but when you have no idea what you're doing, you have to compensate for that by being really good at describing what you are trying to do.  right now, your code is terrible, and your description of what it's supposed to be doing is terrible.

Comment: i've not followed your code, but just wnat to remind that, when you set `temp` to `mat` and making some changes on `mat` will also change `temp`. if you want to assign initial value to temporary value, try `temp = mat[:]` which changes on `mat` will not reflect on `temp`.

Comment: Dude that was sublime text auto add it

Comment: I know what it does should not be there

Comment: What is the intended behavior of the function `repos`?

Comment: reposition of the the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform a deep copy of `listone` in `repos`.

Add `from copy import deepcopy` to the top of the file and then change `modded = listsone` to `modded = deepcopy(listsone)`. At the end of the `repos` function, return `modded`. When you call `repos`, assign the return value to a variable. For example, change `repos('5',mat)` to `some_variable = repos('5',mat)`.

Comment: Ok will try that! :)

Comment: Thanks you so much. That did it!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
from copy import deepcopy

def findpos(element, matrix):
    ii = -1
    jj = -1
    for i in matrix:
        ii += 1
        for o in i:
            if o == element:
                jj = i.index(o)
                return ii, jj

def switchmatrixelements(el1,el2, mat):
    pos1 = findpos(el1,mat)
    pos2 =  findpos(el2,mat)
    modded =  deepcopy(mat)
    modded[pos2[0]][pos2[1]] = el1
    modded[pos1[0]][pos1[1]] = el2
    return modded

mat = [['5','4','1'],
       ['0','6','8'],
       ['7','3','2']]

print mat
print switchmatrixelements('0','5',mat)
print switchmatrixelements('0','7',mat)
```

output:

```
   [['5', '4', '1'], ['0', '6', '8'], ['7', '3', '2']]
   [['0', '4', '1'], ['5', '6', '8'], ['7', '3', '2']]
   [['5', '4', '1'], ['7', '6', '8'], ['0', '3', '2']]
```

Comment: You are getting there the same problem I had. The first run it did fine but in your second run the seven should be in the 0 of main matrix. I solve it with Tyler answer but Thanks for trying :)

Comment: Good point. I'm taking that back, you need a deepcopy :)   Will edit my 'solution' but giving credit to to Tyler!